# PHP PDO display only one record if two or more of the same record with the same value exist

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a PHP code and I have a dropdown list of a list of countries in a SQL database. The values are sorted:

```
Continent (Row 1) - > Country (Row 2) -> City (Row 3)
```

Eg.

```
Europe -> England -> London
Europe -> England -> London
Europe -> Gemany -> Munich
North America -> New York -> Manhattan
North America -> California -> Los Angeles
```

I have a drop down for the first column (continent) which displays
Europe, Europe, North America, North America

I would like to display Europe and North America only once i.e. have duplicates or more display only once.

This is my code

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tableName = 'categories';

//Get values from table
$sqlUpdate = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$sqlUpdate->execute();


echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="continent" onChange="this.form.submit()" size = "4"> ';
while ($result = $sqlUpdate->fetch()) {
    echo '<option value="';
    echo $result['continent'];
    echo '">';
    echo $result['continent'];
    echo '</option>'; 
}
echo '</select>'; 
echo '</form>'; 
echo '<p><strong>You have selected</strong> <em>'.$_POST['country'].'</em></p>';
```

How do I go about it please?

Comment: SELECT * FROM $tableName GROUP BY continent

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM $tableName

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM $tableName GROUP BY continent or SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM $tableName

both work.

Thank you